# Installing .net Framework 4 and keeping 3.5

Tags: .net

If I install framework 4 will it replace framework 3.5? I still work on many applications using framework 3.5 which I do not plan to migrate in the near future however I'd like to use framework 4 for new projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it will remain there and wont cause any conflicts.  .NET 4 And visual studio 2010 allow .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008 to be ran side by side.

Answer (score 3):

An install of .NET 4 will not replace .NET 3.5.

You are free to continue developing .NET 3.5 apps as well as .NET 4.0 apps on the same development machine; you may sometimes have to juggle your PATH envar, if you use msbuild, but even that isn't a problem.

You can even continue developing .NET 2.0 if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem.  .NET 4.0 is the first version in a long time that installs side-by-side with previous versions of the framework.  .NET 2.0 was previous-to-last one that supported this, installing .NET 3.0 or 3.5 would replace it.  Although the term "improve it" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the 4.0 framework will not overwrite or remove the previous frameworks (2.0, 3.0, 3.5 etc).  .NET 4.0 will run side by side with .NET 2.0+.   If you're using Visual studio 2010, you just have to make sure to choose the framework you want to work with when you start up a new project.